# Mule Capturing Oracle DB Change Notification

Tags: oracle11g

I'm pretty New to Java and Mulesoft, I have been working on one POC. It's nothing but capturing the Database Change Notification in Mule, where DB polling cannot be implemented due to performance issues & Datamapper cannot be used. Can anyone suggest me the right approach on this. Below is my sample code on which I have been working.

```
<db:oracle-config name="Oracle_Configuration" host="localhost" port="1521" instance="xe" user="HR" password="hr" doc:name="Oracle Configuration1"/>
    <file:connector name="OutPutFile" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" outputAppend="true" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].txt" dynamicNotification="true" writeToDirectory="C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\MulesoftExamples"/>
<db:oracle-config name="Oracle_Configuration1" url="jdbc:thin.oracle://localhost:1521/HR" doc:name="Oracle Configuration1" transactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="1521" basePath="alertcapture" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<file:endpoint path="C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\MulesoftExamples" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].txt" connector-ref="File" name="File" responseTimeout="10000" encoding="UTF-8" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="alertcaptureFlow">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <db:select config-ref="Oracle_Configuration"   doc:name="ChangeNotify" target="#[flowVars.selectResult]" >
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM nfevents;]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </poll>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/alertcapture/src/main/app" method="GET" doc:name="FetchData"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/alertcapture/src/main/app" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].txt" connector-ref="OutPutFile" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Alertcapture"  encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" ref="File"/>
</flow>
```

>